# Flask-SQLAlchemy JSON column returning stringified JSON

Tags: python, json, sqlalchemy

I am using SQLite for development and Postgres in production.  I have a model defined as:

```py
class Strategy(db.Model):
    ...
    details = db.Column(db.JSON, nullable=False)
```

When I query this table, I am getting returned a stringified version of the dict.  I expect that SQLAlchemy should be handling this gracefully:

```py
>>> db.session.query(Strategy.details).first()
('{"sports": ["6"], "solicitation_schedule": "hourly", "solicitation_start": "2020-04-09 20:00:00"}',)
```

Why is this not coming back as a Python dictionary object?  Is there a solve that avoids creating my own field type?

Comment: Cannot reproduce. What version of SQLA and SQLite are you using (I'm assuming the problem arises with SQLite). How do you insert the data? It is btw. not a great idea to develop against 1 DB product and use another in production in general, unless you're ready to settle for a common subset of features etc.

Comment: Great point, I am using `json.dumps` to insert the data.  Let me test out without.  I used `json.dumps` to more easy coerce `datetime.datetime` objects to str.  I likely should handle that separately.

Comment: @IljaEverilä - thank you for the pointer! Solved. :)